# undefined reference to function, when using if defined on Windows (on Linux its ok)

Tags: c++, c, undefined-reference

I have a strange problem. I have those files:

**lib.h:**

```
#ifndef _LIB_H_
#define _LIB_H_

double fun(int a);

#endif
```

**lib.c:**

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#if !defined(MY_FUN) && ((defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)) && defined(_X86_))
#define MY_FUN
double fun(int a)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
#endif
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "lib.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fun(2);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run such code on Windows, I have an error: `undefined reference to fun`. **On Linux (Ubuntu) its ok, compiling without errors.** When I put everything in one file (on Windows) its ok as well. But I need to have it in separete files. How to make it right? On Windows Im using MinGW with Code::Blocks.

Comment: The `#if` in lib.c seems unnecessary complicated. Care to explain what you were trying to do there?

Comment: how do you manage to format that code? I didn't manage to... is there anything particular you did?

Comment: @doctorlove: yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code::Blocks probably compiles your .c file as C code, while on linux you're compiling everything as C++ code, e.g. by invoking g++ directly.

You need to tell that the `fun` function has C linkage, so lib.h should have this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double fun(int a);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

You'll naturally also need to double check that at least one of the conditions in your lib.c file are evaluates to true

```
  #if !defined(MY_FUN) && ((defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)) && (defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)) && defined(_X86_))
```

(so at least try by removing that whole #if )

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! Just added `extern ...` in my `*.h` file and it worked :) Could you tell me, what exactly does it mean? Or where I can read about this more?

Comment: @yak see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure you can use logical operators with the preprocessor, it might depend on your toolchain;
2. The `#define MY_FUN` and `!defined(MY_FUN)` are unnecessary, since you won't compile the file twice;
3. There is probably at least one more file in your project which plays a role with this problem since, as I expected, this code

   #if (defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)) && (defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)) && defined(_X86_) 
   random error!!!
   #endif

   int main(){
           return 0;
   }

compiles smoothly on

> g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
>   as well as on
>   gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

(sorry about the formatting, I didn't manage to make it look good).

Comment: I know it compiles on Ubuntu ... but on Windows it doesnt ... When I put everything in one `*.cpp` file on Windows it compiles just fine with Code::Blocks. Any solutions? There are any other files in my project, just those I pasted here ;)

Comment: nope, my point is: on ubuntu your #if clause causes its "content" not to be seen by the compiler (in my example, the line "random error!!!" does not get complained at by the compiler. On Ubuntu, then, if you just try to compile what you posted on the question, it won't compile (due to the lack of the definition of fun.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks:) so I need to add some `if defined` for ubuntu too! Cheers

Comment: I don't see the point of those defines however. Are you sure you need them?